# Unable to scrape table using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape the following webpage using selenium https://www.stakingrewards.com/cryptoassets/, butI keep getting the same error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? It seems like it can't find the class name for some reason. The error I am getting is the following

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".table-wrap"}
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

driver.get(f'https://www.stakingrewards.com/cryptoassets/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("table-wrap")
html = BeautifulSoup(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element), 'html.parser')

for item in html.findAll('div', {"class": "rt-tr-group"}):
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I always find elements using the full xPath. For me it has been a lot more reliable, and since there can be multiple occurrences of a class name I recommend not using that. What you can do is right-click the webpage and press inspect, find the element you're looking for, right-click the element, and press copy full xpath.

Replace:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("table-wrap")
```

with:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/section/main/div/div/section/section[2]')
```

Furthermore, you are trying to act on the driver variable with BeautifulSoup, which does not work. You have to pass BeautifulSoup the URL and keep going. I am unfamiliar with BeautifulSoup and can't help you much there :/

Comment: im getting AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_full_xpath'

Comment: My bad, try:
"element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/section/main/div/div/section/section[2]')"
if that doesn't work try
"element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/section/main/div/div/section/section[2]')"

Comment: I edited my response to match these edits.

Comment: thank you, but that outputs a null value

Comment: try element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/section/main/div/div/section/section[2]').text

If this does not work it's because you are trying to scrape every table on the page, but you have to scrape every element in a table.